# How to use sublime text 2 like notepad++

Tags: sublimetext2

In Notepad ++ we can use *Move to other view* for copy/paste attributes easily . But How i use sublime text 2 like two windows at a time for copy/paste attributes easily ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right you will find the answer by accessing sublime's menu View>Layout>... Columns